# jQuery EasyUI - Add link to cell

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables: Customer Contact. Table contact has a foreign key pointing at the customer table.

```
<table id="dgContactSearch" title="Suche" class="easyui-datagrid" style="height:160px" 
                            url="getContacts.php"
                            toolbar="#toolbarContactSearch" pagination="true"
                            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th field="customer_id" width="50">Customer</th>
                                <th field="name" width="50">Name</th>
                                <th field="function" width="50">Funktion</th>
                                <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
                                <th field="mobile" width="50">Mobile</th>
                                <th field="fax" width="50">Fax</th>
                                <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
                                <th field="comment" width="50">Commnent</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

here is the php file

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $searchItemContact = isset($_POST['searchItemContact']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchItemContact']) : '';

    $searchItemContact = htmlentities($searchItemContact, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

    $result = array();

    $where = "name like '%$searchItemContact%' OR function like '%$searchItemContact%' OR email like '%$searchItemContact%' OR comment like '%$searchItemContact%'";
    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from contact where " . $where);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];

    $rs = mysql_query("select * from contact where " . $where . " limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;
    echo json_encode($result);
```

I want to make the `<th field="customer_id" width="50">Customer</th>` linkable . i.e. `<a href="customerView.php?id=$customer_id>#</a>`
So when I load the table I see the customer name instaed of the id and make a link to th e customer page!
Please help.

**Update**

I managed somehow a little workaround:

```
<th data-options="field:'name',width:100,align:'left',formatter:formatCustomerId">Name</th>
```

and then Javascript function that goes along:

```
function formatCustomerId(val,row){
    var url = "customerView.php?id=";
    return '<a href="'+url + row.customer_id+'">'+val+'</a>';
}
```

Comment: You should post the jquery code too

Comment: The one which initiate your datagrid

Comment: Just a write a query to extract the name of the customer like `select cus.customer_name from Customer cus,Contact con where cus.id=con.id`. so you can Use name inplace of ID and make it linkable via Jquery

Comment: Where you want the links in table body tr's on the costumer cell?

Comment: Yes! I want the link in the customer cell.

Comment: Did you tried with data attribute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final solution was a mixture of all the previous answers :).

```
<table id="dgContactSearch" title="Benutzer Suche" class="easyui-datagrid" style="height:160px" 
                            url="getContacts.php"
                            toolbar="#toolbarContactSearch" pagination="true"
                            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-options="field:'firma',width:80,align:'left',formatter:formatCustomerId">Kunde</th>
                                <th data-options="field:'name',width:50,align:'left',formatter:formatContactUrl">Name</th>
                                <th field="function" width="50">Funktion</th>
                                <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
                                <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
                                <th field="mobile" width="50">Mobile</th>
                                <th field="fax" width="50">Fax</th>

                                <th field="comment" width="120">Kommentare</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
</table>
```

The script:

```
<script>
function formatCustomerId(val,row){
    var url = "customerView.php?id=";
    return '<a href="'+url + row.customer_id+'">'+val+'</a>';
}

function formatContactUrl(val,row){
    var url = "contactView.php?id=";
    return '<a href="'+url + row.id+'">'+val+'</a>';
}
</script>
```

and the getContacts.php

```
<?php
    include 'includes/db_functions.php';
    db_link();

    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $searchItemContact = isset($_POST['searchItemContact']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchItemContact']) : '';

    $searchItemContact = htmlentities($searchItemContact, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

    $result = array();

    $where = "name like '%$searchItemContact%' OR function like '%$searchItemContact%' OR customer.name like '%$searchItemContact%' OR email like '%$searchItemContact%' OR comment like '%$searchItemContact%'";
    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from contact where " . $where);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];


    $sql = "SELECT contact.*, customer.name
    FROM `contact`
    INNER JOIN `kunden` on contact.customer_id = kunden.id ";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql . "where " . $where . " limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;
    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. The "official" advice is way much heavy to implement than this "one cell only formatter" : http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1725.0

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of links i use an data-url attribute to save the url i want to redirect, then use jquery to redirect the user, ex:

In you server side when you generate the table, write the data-url attribute where you want to associate a link:

```
<td class='customer_whatever' data-url='<?= $customer_page_url ?>'> Customer Name</td>
```

In jQuery catch all and add onclick event:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if($(this).data('url')){
      $(this).click(function(){

        $(location).attr('href',$(this).data('url'));
      });
  }
});
```

In css don't forget to put:

```
.customer_whatever{ cursor:pointer;}
```

This is a small working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9XA3k/1/

Comment: The problem in this case is that I have no control over the <td> tags. I only have control over the <th> tags. How can I access the <td> tags individually and customize the content coming from the json array????