# jeasyui - how to replace text with image

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Is there a way in jeasyui to replace text with image? I need to replace words "Yes" and "No" with images in all results under th Status. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#dg').datagrid({
        view: detailview,
        detailFormatter:function(index,row){
            return '<div class="ddv"></div>';
        },
        onExpandRow: function(index,row){
            var ddv = $(this).datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('div.ddv');
            ddv.panel({
                border:false,
                cache:false,
                href:'show_form_RO.php?ID='+row.ID,
                onLoad:function(){
                    $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
                }
            });
            $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
        },
        rowStyler:function(index,row){
            if (row.Status=='No'){
                return 'background-color:pink;color:blue;font-weight:bold;';
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="dg" style="width: 1100px; height: 550px" url="get_records.php" toolbar="#toolbar"
        pagination="true" fitcolumns="true" singleselect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="Checkedby" width="50" sortable="true">
                    Checked By
                </th>
                <th field="Status" width="50" sortable="true">
                    Successful?
                </th>
                <th field="Date" width="50" sortable="true">
                    Date
                </th>
                <th field="Notes" width="50">
                    Explain if backup failed
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I tried to add this script to the head but it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dg:contains('1')").html(function (_, html) {
     return html.replace(/\b1\b/,"<img src='images/ok.png' />");
});
    $("#dg:contains('-1')").html(function (_, html) {
     return html.replace(/-1/,"<img src='images/fail.gif' />")
});
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The code you tried uses a class selector, but I do not see that class within the code you posted. Should you have used an id selector instead?

Comment: I changed it to id selector but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery EasyUI - Add link to cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061894/jquery-easyui-add-link-to-cell)

Comment: I suggest to check answers to question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061894/jquery-easyui-add-link-to-cell . The question is not exactly the same but both problems can be solved exactly the same way.